# Macro value changed while being assigned

Tags: c

I don't know how to express my problem. The code is below, please tell me why the value of `a` got changed? In my opinion, the `GET macro` just returns the value of `a`, NOT the address of `a`...

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define GET(addr) (*(int *)(&addr))

int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    GET(a) = 20;
    printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

Comment: Of course it cannot change the addres of a. I changes the value that is stored at the address of a. Which is a, BTW.

Comment: I would be interrested to know your theory about what should happen and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A result of dereferencing a pointer is an [*L-value*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-value), because it has an address; it certainly can be assigned.

Consider a simpler example: if `p` is an array or a pointer, you can certainly assign to `p[0]`, as in

```
p[0] = 20;
```

Now recall that `p[0]` is the same as `*p`. Now expand your macro:

```
*((int*)&a) = 20;
```

This is equivalent to

```
(&a)[0] = 20;
```

which is certainly a valid (albeit somewhat unorthodox) assignment of the `a` itself.

Answer (score 3):

When you expand your macro you get:

```
(*(int *)(&a)) = 20
```

Forget the `(int *)` and you get

```
(*(&a)) = 20
```

Which is equal to:

```
a = 20;
```

Hence you are changing the value of `a`!

Answer (score 1):

The `GET(a) = 20` line expands to:

```
(*(int *)(&a)) = 20;
```

Let's get rid of the redundant cast and the outer parentheses:

```
*(&a) = 20;
```

This is clearly an assignment to `a` as it's equivalent to:

```
a = 20;
```

If your objective is to prevent accidental use of `GET()` as an lvalue, you could change it like so:

```
#define GET(addr) ((int)addr)
```

With this, trying to compile your code fails with

```
test.c:8:12: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

Answer (score 1):

Say you had:

```
int *b = ...;
*b = 10;
```

What the above does is assign 10 to the integer that `b` points to.

Your macro does pretty much the same thing, with `b` replaced by `&a` (and a no-op cast).